# Serilog filter RequestPath

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-2.2, health-check

I have problems to exclude healthchecks from serilog files.

1. Serilog.Filters.Expressions are installed and the StatusCode=200 line will be filtered.
2. appsettings:

   ```
   "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Verbose",
          "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
        "AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI": "Warning",
            "HealthChecks": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "Using": ["Serilog.Filters.Expressions"],
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByExcluding",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck') and StatusCode=200"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
              "configure": [
                {
                  "Name": "File",
                  "Args": {
                    "path": "C:/Logs/MyApi/log.txt",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                    "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                    "buffered": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   ```

3.Programm

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting web host");
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                return 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
               {
                   loggerConfiguration.Enrich.FromLogContext()
                     .WriteTo.Elasticsearch()
                   .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                   Log.Information("App started");
               });
```

The logs changed from

> 2020-11-04 23:59:44.128 +01:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET
> https://servicesp-rbg.company.com/MyApi/healthcheck   2020-11-04
> 23:59:44.128 +01:00 [INF] Request finished in 0.211ms 200 text/plain

to

> 2020-11-06 14:27:32.787 +01:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET
> https://servicesp-rbg.company.com/My.Api/healthcheck

so the statuscode=200 filter is working but not the RequestPath 'healthcheck'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution
"expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck') AND StatusCode=200"

Replaced AND by OR

"expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck') OR StatusCode=200"